# Upper bounds estimates of Minkowski sum

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $A,B \subset \{0,...,d\}^n$, do we have any result that says $|A+B| \leq \mathcal{O}_d(|A|\cdot |B|)^\tau$ for $\tau < 1$. The case $\tau = 1$ is trivial, and due to the restricted setting, I am expecting some sort of shrinkage.

Comment: In many cases $|A+B|$ equals $|A||B|$, e.g. let $A=\{2^k:\text{$0\leq k\leq\log_2 d$ is even}\}^n$ and $B=\{2^k:\text{$0\leq k\leq\log_2 d$ is odd}\}^n$.

Comment: I am treating d as a constant so can't such cases be covered by a constant dependent on d?

Comment: If you allow a constant depending on $d$, then there is the trivial bound $|A+B|\leq (d+1)^n$. The right-hand side is a constant depending on $d$, and hence you can take $\tau=0$. Please be more specific on what type of estimate you want.

Comment: I am taking d to be constant and n to be the free parameter so (d+1)^n can't be absorbed in the Big-Oh. For simplicity you can even assume d = 2.

Comment: OK, then please update your $\mathcal{O}$ to $\mathcal{O}_d$. This will make it clear that you allow the implied constant to depend on $d$ but not on $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As GH from MO said, there are plenty of sets $A,B\subset \Bbb{Z}$ where $|A+B|=|A||B|$, taking products of these such sets shows you can’t absorb these into the $O_d(\cdot)$.

For example take $d\ge 3$, $A= \{0,1\}^n, B = \{0,2\}^n$. Then $|A+B| = \{0,1,2,3\}^n$.